# What am I? Your hobby might help you answer

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> *A blazing orb that, skyward hurled, 
>
>   will lead to gates beneath the world. 
>
>   Twelve more set 'round, the gate will send 
>
>   the unprepared to meet their end.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be describing

> An Eye of Ender in Minecraft

> A blazing orb that, skyward hurled,  
> will lead to gates beneath the world.

> An Eye of Ender is an orb crafted from an Ender Pearl and Blaze Powder and has a fiery texture.
>  When used, it is thrown into the sky and travels toward an End Portal, which is found in a subterranean fortress.

> Twelve more set 'round, the gate will send 
>  
> the unprepared to meet their end.

> An End Portal can be activated by filling each of the 12 blocks it is made of with an Eye of Ender.
>  After activating it, the player can travel through it to the End, which starts a boss fight which will likely kill the unprepared.